# How to switch off automatic system and app updates?

Tags: ouya

I'm fine with updates in general, getting rid of bugs is fine after all, but when I just want to quickly play a short game in my break while the OUYA determines there is an update and applies it without any chance of intervention, this is rather annoying. The same applies to the game itself - once an update is available, I cannot start it until the update was applied. So

> How to change the update behaviour such that I only get a notification about updates being available, while manually choosing *when* to apply them?

Hint: I know I could detach the OUYA from the internet, but a) using WLAN this means I have to either switch the OUYA WLAN off/on manually or kill my WLAN router and b) an available update shouldn't prevent me from using apps that *do* require internet access, e.g. the web browser

Comment: Just build a Faraday Cage around your Ouya. Then whenever you want to connect to the internet, you just remove the Faraday Cage from around it. Completely practical!

Comment: Great solution :-P

Answer (score 2):

This [OUYA forum](http://ouyaforum.com/showthread.php?3911-Can-u-really-turn-off-Automatic-Updates) says that:

> You can go into the advanced settings, scroll down to Accounts, click OUYA, and uncheck Updates. I don't know if this actually works for OTA updates, but if there is a way, that would be it.

This would suggest that there is a way of turning off updates but they aren't sure if it applies to everything.

Comment: Ah, the post above that one claims this was just introduced with an update from July 1st, which would explain why I haven't seen that option. I'll verify this at home before I accept the answer though...

Comment: I did this and yet the OUYA still downloaded the next update without hesitation and re-checked that mark

Comment: hmm, by all means dont accept mine then, the OUYA seems to ba having habits of destroying peoples expectations lately! Ill poke around and see if i can find an alternate method for you

Comment: Although I am not 100% sure that I didn't download one update manually and _that_ re-checked the mark, triggering the next automatic update. I'll check when the next update is available

Comment: Ok, I can definitely confirm this does not work, and OUYA support replied with "unfortunately there are no plans to allow updates to be optional at this point [...] but I will be sure to pass your request along for you". The latter part was only added after I reopened that ticket though, so I somehow doubt it is seriously considered :( So for now apparently the only way to switch off auto-updates is rooting your OUYA, which I try to avoid for now...